# display a date field, for the user to enter a specific date range

Tags: iphone

Hi i am new to iphone application development..
i want to design a view, where i want to show the bank transaction from date x to date Y
now i want the user to enter this date x & y. Please suggest me  the best way for the user to enter the dates .how should i start.

i saw date picker, but i think it looks too big, because it occupies most of my screen.
Else can i make the date pickers visibility off, when i set the focus out from my date fields.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [jQueryUI's](http://www.jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/) date picker, it's pretty slick

Comment: please briefly tell me, how am i to use it in iphone .
it seems to be used in web application

Comment: I not sure it will work. I think I missed that you were building an iPhone app (sorry). If you're interested, you can check out phonegap and use jQTouch to build native iPhone apps using JavaScript/jQuery, HTML, & CSS.